# The controller 'AdminSceneController' has no event slot 'logout' - JavaFX Error

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a simple button, but I am getting this stupid error and it doesn't make any sense.

Here is my Admin Scene FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="582.0" stylesheets="@application.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="appController.AdminSceneController">
   <children>
      <Separator layoutX="-14.0" layoutY="101.0" prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="601.0" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="29.0" text="admin panel">
         <font>
            <Font name="Book Antiqua" size="28.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button layoutX="174.0" layoutY="32.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-radius: 100px;" text="+" textFill="#369033" />
      <Button fx:id="logoutButton" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logout" prefHeight="3.0" prefWidth="81.0" styleClass="logout" stylesheets="@application.css" text="(logout)" textFill="#070707" />
      <Button layoutX="387.0" layoutY="392.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="Delete" />
      <ListView layoutX="223.0" layoutY="106.0" prefHeight="327.0" prefWidth="128.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

And this is my AdminSceneController.java

```
package appController;

import appDesign.PhotoAlbum;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class AdminSceneController {

    public class MainSceneController {

        @FXML
        Button logoutButton;

        @FXML
        public void logout(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
            PhotoAlbum.primaryStage.show();
            ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        }

    }

}
```

I get a warning from Eclipse saying:

```
The controller 'AdminSceneController' has no event slot 'logout'
```

And when I run the program, I get the error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#logout', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/Peter/Documents/GitHub/PhotoAlbum40/bin/appDesign/AdminPanelScene.fxml:19
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AdminSceneController does not have a logout method, your class MainSceneController does though.

Remove the line

```
public class MainSceneController {
```

and the closing `}`and it should work.

Comment: I knew there was some stupid reason for this. I don't know why AdminScene was nested inside of that. Thank you for finding that for me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand, that an inner class (`MainSceneController`) is not the same class as the enclosing class (`AdminSceneController`). By using `fx:controller="appController.AdminSceneController"` in the fxml a instance of `AdminSceneController` is created. This class however does not contain a single method or field. This causes the error.

Furthermore note that the `FXMLLoader` does not allow you to create non-`static` inner classes. *If* you want the `FXMLLoader` to create your controller instance, you have to make `MainSceneController` static and use `fx:controller="appController.AdminSceneController$MainSceneController"`.

Ways around this would be specifying a [`controllerFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) or creating the controller instance yourself:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(...));
AdminSceneController enclosingInstance = new AdminSceneController(); // or any other way to get your hands on a instance of the enclosing class

// specify controller instance used yourself
loader.setController(enclosingInstance.new MainSceneController());

...

loader.load()
```

Which requires you to remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the fxml.

Of course you could also simply move the field / method to a top level class...

Comment: The AdminScene wasn't supposed to be there. I don't know how it happened haha.